# IIS Reverse Proxy Advice

Tags: windows, iis, reverse-proxy

I have Plesk Running on a windows server 2019 and the domain im using has a ssl cert. And runs smoothly.
I have a small bot program running for my community that works with twitch chat it includes an admin panel.

What I'm trying to do is for a domain https://website1.mydomain.com to reroute to the bot running 127.0.0.1:25000/panel through reverse proxy. But I'm having the issue where the domain url gets recognized but nothing is happening afterwards, there's no login page loading just gives me a 404 error.

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voblb.png)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: That sadly didnt help but thank you. I'm really confused, I did everything according microsoft documentation about url rewrite but no luck whatsoever